# How to achieve zero downtime in ETl

Tags: mysql, database, pentaho, etl, data-warehouse

I have an ETL process which takes data from transaction db and keeps after processing stores the data to another DB. While storing the data we are truncating the old data and storing new data to have better performance, as update takes a lot of time than truncate insert. So in this process we experience counts as 0 or wrong data for some time (like for 2 3 mins). We are running the ETL in every 8 hours.

So how can we avoid this problem? How can we achieve zero downtime?

Comment: It has to be a small database when full loading is faster than incremental one. I guess that during update you are  taking all rows from source  instead the rows that has changed from last incremental load.

Comment: We are actually doing some calculations on the data, which needs full data. We can not work with incremental data. It will complicate the logic a lot and may lead to performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

One way we did use in the past was to prepare the prod data in a table named temp. Then when finished (and checked, that was the lengthy part in our process), drop prod and rename the temp in prod.

Takes almost no time, and the process was successful even in case some other users were locking the table.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But what will be the impact on the existing queries running on the prod at that time? Those queries will get killed and the users will not get any response. Correct me if I am wrong